# ARCore how to add Virtual object as soon as horizontal plane detected

Tags: android, arcore

In ARCore sample,How to add Virtual object as soon as horizontal plane detected.I tried following code but not works,

```
// Check if we detected at least one plane. If so, hide the loading message.
      if (messageSnackbar != null) {
        for (Plane plane : session.getAllTrackables(Plane.class)) {
          if (plane.getType() == com.google.ar.core.Plane.Type.HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING
                  && plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
            hideLoadingMessage();
            //frame.hitTest(plane.getExtentX(),plane.getExtentZ());

            long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100;

            int metaState = 0;
            MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
                    downTime,
                    eventTime,
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                    plane.getCenterPose().qx(),
                    plane.getCenterPose().qy(),
                    metaState
            );
            //surfaceView.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            onSingleTap(motionEvent);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in `onDrawFrame()`:

inside this loop:

```
 for (Plane plane : session.getAllTrackables(Plane.class)) {
      if (plane.getType() == com.google.ar.core.Plane.Type.HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING
          && plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
        break;
      }
    }
```

add this:

```
 for (Plane plane : session.getAllTrackables(Plane.class)) {
      if (plane.getType() == com.google.ar.core.Plane.Type.HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING
          && plane.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {

          if (newAnchor == null) {
            newAnchor = plane.createAnchor(plane.getCenterPose());
          }

        break;
      }
```

make sure newAnchor is a member variable you don't add more anchors each call to onDrawFrame().

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember you should change TrackingState.TRACKING to TrackingState.NEW

It's not documented yet.